# Create Proper Dataframe from SDMX Response, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, sdmx

I want to prepare dataset from the data available in http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=ATSI_BIRTHS_SUMM

Data API:

http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/ATSI_BIRTHS_SUMM/1+4+5+7+8+9+10+13+14+15+18+19+20.IM+IB.0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7.A/all

```
from pandasdmx import Request

Agency_Code = 'ABS'
Dataset_Id = 'ATSI_BIRTHS_SUMM'

ABS = Request(Agency_Code)
data_response = ABS.data(resource_id='ATSI_BIRTHS_SUMM')
print(data_response.url)

DF = data_response.write(data_response.data.obs(with_values=True, with_attributes=True), parse_time=False)
```

Above gives error: ValueError: Type names and field names cannot be a keyword: 'None'

```
DF = data_response.write(data_response.data.series, parse_time=False), This works but Dimension items coming in column wise.
```

Support Links:

```
http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/all
http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/ATSI_BIRTHS_SUMM
http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=ATSI_BIRTHS_SUMM
```

Please suggest better way to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

Your example

```py
DF = data_response.write(data_response.data.series, parse_time=False)
```

Produces a stacked DataFrame, by `unstack().reset_index()` you will get a "flat" DataFrame.

```py
data_response.write().unstack().reset_index()
```

```
  MEASURE INDIGENOUS_STATUS ASGS_2011 FREQUENCY TIME_PERIOD       0
0       1                IM         0         A        2001  8334.0
```

Is this what you are looking for?